# From axis2 function call, which is in another jar is not called and no error also shown

Tags: grails, apache-axis

I have recently migrated my environment from Java 6 to Java 7. Installed Netbeans 8.0.2. A Grails(Version 2.1.1) project is running in it.

From Grails project using withREST a web service is called in another Tomcat (Version 8). This tomcat(version 8) is using axis2 to expose the methods. A java class "OneWebservice.java". Built as aar file and deployed.

Code is like this.

```
import com.project.Two.TwoFunction;

import com.project.Three.ThreeFunction;

public class OneWebservice{

     function getOneandTwo()
     {
           com.project.Two.TwoFunction();
           .....
           com.project.Three.ThreeFunction();    
     }
}
```

When function getOneandTwo() is called, in the above code Two.TwoFunction is called, while Three.ThreeFunction is not called. No error is also printed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Got this fixed.
We have Solr implemented for text based search.
Import related to Solr was there in com.project.Three.ThreeFunction this class file

```
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrQuery;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.response.QueryResponse;
import org.apache.solr.common.SolrDocument;
import org.apache.solr.common.SolrDocumentList;
```

was giving problem, if this is commented its working fine...
I think Solr is not working in Java 8 and Tomcat 8